# Filter 2 different nodes in E4X?

Tags: javascript, xml, filter, e4x

Can I filter 2 different node types in E4X same as attributes but then on node type? I cannot find this anywhere:

Something like":

```
$.book_xml.pages.page.(node == 'front' && node =='back');


<pages>
 <page>
  <front></front>
  <back></back>
 </page>
<pages>
```

Comment: Given your fragment, why would a node ever be "front" AND "back"? Surely, they'd be one OR the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with e4x in javascript but this works in actionscript:

```
trace(book_xml.pages.page.*.(localName()=="front" || localName()=="back"));
```

Returns both the front and back nodes.